# What does \psGetDistance do?

Tags: pstricks, pstricks-add

friends,

I wonder if `\psGetDistance` is somehow related to euclidean distance or what is it about? Here is a minimum working example that my explain :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{fp}
\def\distance(#1,#2)(#3,#4){
\FPset\hjsxi{#1}
\FPset\hjsxii{#3}
\FPset\hjsyi{#2}
\FPset\hjsyii{#4}
\FPsub\hjsxa\hjsxii\hjsxi
\FPmul\hjsxa\hjsxa\hjsxa
\FPsub\hjsya\hjsyii\hjsyi
\FPmul\hjsya\hjsya\hjsya
\FPadd\hjsz\hjsxa\hjsya
\FPeval\hjsz{root(2,\hjsz)}
\FPeval\hjsz{round(\hjsz,2)}
\FPeval\hjsz{clip(\hjsz)}
\hjsz}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
Note that:\\
\verb+(1) \psGetDistance(-2,1)( 3, 1)\DVal \DVal+ = \psGetDistance(-2,1)(3,1)\DVal \DVal\\
\verb+(2) \psGetDistance(-2,1)(-3,-1)\DVal \DVal+ = \psGetDistance(-2,1)(-3,-1)\DVal \DVal\\
\verb+(3) \psGetDistance(-2,0)( 3,-1)\DVal \DVal+ = \psGetDistance(-2,0)( 3,-1)\DVal \DVal\\\\
However rounded distance is\\
\verb+(4) \distance(-2,1)( 3, 1)+ = \distance(-2,1)(3,1)\\
\verb+(5) \distance(-2,1)(-3,-1)+ = \distance(-2,1)(-3,-1)\\
\verb+(6) \distance(-2,0)( 3,-1)+ = \distance(-2,0)(3,-1)\\
\end{document}
```

Ihis is the output:

[image: Output of the mwe]

The results (1)-(3) corresponds to the documentation of pstricks-add. However there are no explaining details given. The results (4)-(6) are euclidean distances.

Kind Regards

Hans

Comment: It is a bug with the old code. Will be fixed ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with an up-to-date `PSTricks-add`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}
    
Note that:

\verb+(1) \psGetDistance(-2,1)( 3, 1)\DVal \DVal+ = \psGetDistance(-2,1)(3,1)\CVal \CVal\\
\verb+(2) \psGetDistance(-2,1)(-3,-1)\DVal \DVal+ = \psGetDistance[3](-2,1)(-3,-1)\CVal 
\CVal\\
\verb+(3) \psGetDistance(-2,0)( 3,-1)\DVal \DVal+ = \psGetDistance[5](-2,0)( 3,-1)\CVal 
\CVal
    
\end{document}
```

[image]